# Asignar nombre de interfaz fijo a una direccion MAC

Tags: raspberry-pi, macos

Estoy trabajando con una raspberry pi la cual solo tiene una tarjeta de red (un puerto ethernet). Para tener mas tarjetas de red, utilizo unos dispositivos externos que convierten de USB a ethernet. El problema es que cada vez que se reinicia la raspberry, ésta asigna aleatoriamente el nombre de interfaz con el dispositivo.

Me gustaría hacer que de alguna manera la raspberry al detectar que se trata de una MAC (la que quiero yo) asignase el nombre de interfaz que quiero yo; es decir, por ejemplo la `MAC 00:50:56:c0:00:08` con el nombre de interfaz `eth2`

He probado a crear un fichero llamado `70-persistent-net.rules` en `/etc/udev/rules.d` e incluir la siguiente regla:

> SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*",
>   ATTR{address}=="00:50:56:c0:00:08", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0",
>   ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth2"

Al reiniciar la raspberry no me asigna la MAC con el nombre de la interfaz.

¿Habría alguna otra posibilidad de llevarlo a cabo?

Gracias.

Comment: Sería conveniente que aportaras más información. Por ejemplo ifconfig

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiarle el nombre de la interfaz de red debes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Consulta el nombre de la interfaz de red mediante el comando `ifconfig`

   [image: Apuntamos tanto el nombre como la MAC]
2. Una vez conozcas las direcciones mac hay que modificar el nombre de la interfaz de red. Edita el fichero */etc/udev/rules.d/10-network.rules* Por ejemplo: `sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/10-network.rules` y añade el siguiente texto, en tu caso...

> SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="00:50:56:c0:00:08", NAME="eth2"

3. A continuación tienes que acceder al fichero de configuración */etc/network/interfaces* y editarlo. Por ejemplo: `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` y modificar aquellas menciones a las interfaces de red antiguas por los nuevos nombres de ellas.